# What's the difference between public internal, private internal and private external?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, site, communication-site

I want to create a communication site just for my own department.

When I create the site it asks me:

[image]

What does those option mean? What is the differents between Private internal and external?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the description suggests, when you will select "Private Internal" as a confidentiality for your SharePoint site, you will not be able to share the site with guests users from another tenant.

While if you use "Private External", you will be able to share the site with guests users as well.

For your requirements if you want to share the site with only  limited users from your tenant (particular department) and you do not want to share it with guest users, you should use "Private Internal" confidentiality label.